# How to import plugins using WebPack 2 (jQuery & ddSlick)

Tags: npm, webpack, asp.net-core, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to create SP aplication using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Vue.js. In that process I'm stuck with importing/implementing some additional plugins. It was more or less straight forward till I wanted to add ddSlick an JQuery 1.7.2.

First, I implemented jQuery but only v 3.3. and I wanted to add additional v. 1.7.2. which is neccesery for ddSlick to work properly.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $; window.$ = $;

import ddSlick from 'ddslick'
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router/index'
import store from './store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import App from 'components/app-root'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from './icons'

// Registration of global components
Vue.component('icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.prototype.$http = axios

sync(store, router)

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  ...App
})

export {
  app,
  router,
  store
}
```

I tried with import ddSlick from 'ddslick' but it returns error

```
'Module not found: Error: `Can't resolve 'ddslick' in C:\Develop\someApp-app\someApp.Frontend\ClientApp'`
```

and in console I get

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ddslick"
```

I installed aditional dependencies using npm install as you can see here

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "detached-jquery-1.7.2": "^1.7.2",
    "ddslick": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "vuex": "^2.5.0",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^4.3.2"
  }
```

Thank you for your time :)

**SamBokai** suggested to create npm ls to post results (posting just part of it)
and as we can see ddslick is installed

```
 +-- postcss-modules-scope@1.1.0
| | +-- css-selector-tokenizer@0.7.0 deduped
| | `-- postcss@6.0.23
| |   +-- chalk@2.4.1
| |   | +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
| |   | | `-- color-convert@1.9.2 deduped
| |   | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 deduped
| |   | `-- supports-color@5.4.0 deduped
| |   +-- source-map@0.6.1
| |   `-- supports-color@5.4.0
| |     `-- has-flag@3.0.0 deduped
| +-- postcss-modules-values@1.3.0
| | +-- icss-replace-symbols@1.1.0
| | `-- postcss@6.0.23
| |   +-- chalk@2.4.1
| |   | +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
| |   | | `-- color-convert@1.9.2 deduped
| |   | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 deduped
| |   | `-- supports-color@5.4.0 deduped
| |   +-- source-map@0.6.1
| |   `-- supports-color@5.4.0
| |     `-- has-flag@3.0.0 deduped
| `-- source-list-map@0.1.8
+-- ddslick@1.0.2
| `-- jquery@2.2.4
+-- detached-jquery-1.7.2@1.7.2
+-- eslint@4.19.1
| +-- ajv@5.5.2
| | +-- co@4.6.0
| | +-- fast-deep-equal@1.1.0
| | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0
| | `-- json-schema-traverse@0.3.1
| +-- babel-code-frame@6.26.0 deduped
| +-- chalk@2.4.1
```

2. UPDATE

Here is screenshot of my folderstructure

[image]

Comment: Did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: @SamBokai Yes I did. I used npm install ddslick@1.0.2 --save

Comment: Can you do an `npm ls` and post the result?

Answer (score 1):

Other projects, imported it using another path:

`import '../lib/jquery.ddslick.js';`

References:

https://github.com/binary-com/webtrader-charts/blob/545f5350074d3933346bddb6b04618f49d1b439c/src/common/rivetsExtra.js#L6

https://github.com/rodergstep/cleaning/blob/7eb5f0c2daed7e49ea327af1e7af0b476b9eefb0/src/js/app.js#L1

Comment: hmm, I believe that we are one step closer but unfortunately this did not work. :(

Comment: Let me set up a small project on my machine and test this.

Comment: @Thank you Sam :)

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using detached-jquery. Since jquery is detached from the global namespace, the plugin (ddslick) can not register.. I would either switch to normal jquery and then load ddslick via https like suggested by the ddslick developer (http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) or find out how to load the plugins with detached-jquery.

Comment: Thank you, I ll try that :)